# Shallow testing error - Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-test-renderer

I am doing shallow testing. Here is my container component code:

```
 class jcpenney1 extends Component {
        render() {
        const formId = uuidv1();
        return (
            <FormComponent formId={formId}>
                <HeaderJCpenny1 parentId={formId}>
                </HeaderJCpenny1>
                <FormBodyComponent parentId={formId}>
                                <AddressJCpenney1 classname="address" textalign="right" addressWidth="100%">
                        <WordJCpenney1 />
                    </AddressJCpenney1>
                </FormBodyComponent>
            </FormComponent>
        );
        }
export default jcpenney1;
```

**jcpenney1.test.js** page:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, configure, mount, render} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import jcpenney1 from '../../containers/jcpenney/jcpenney1';
import FormComponent from '../../components/FormComponent/FormComponent';
import FormBodyComponent from '../../components/FormBodyComponent/FormBodyComponent';

import uuidv1 from 'uuid';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
describe('JC penney1 container testing', () =>{
    let wrapper;
    const propIds ={
        formId: uuidv1(),
        word:"JCPenney Header",
        dynamicWordId: uuidv1()
    }
    it('should render all the components', () => {

        wrapper = renderer
        .create(<FormComponent children={mockedChildren} formId={propIds.formId}/>).toJSON();        
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
    it('should render components which are wrapped with <HeaderJCpenny1 /> ', () => {        
        wrapper = mount(<HeaderJCpenny1 textalign="left" fontweight="bold" fontsize="16px" position="relative" parentId={propIds.formId}>
                        <TextBodyComponent>
                            <LogoJCpenney1 logopath="http://jpcpenny.com/logo.png" logowidth="306"></LogoJCpenney1>
                            <LineJCpenney1>                           
                                    <WordJCpenney1 wordVal={propIds.word} wordIndex={1} wordSecId={propIds.dynamicWordId} classname="logoJCpenney1" textalign="center" fontFamily="'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif" wordFontsize="71px" fontWeight="bold" letterSpacing="13px" paddingTop="10px" paddingBottom="0" paddingRight="10px" paddingLeft="10px" wordLineheight="81px" display="block" wordspacing="20px" wordPosition="absolute" wordTop="-13px" opacity="0">Company</WordJCpenney1>
                            </LineJCpenney1>                            
                        </TextBodyComponent> 
                    </HeaderJCpenny1>)        
        expect(wrapper.find(LogoJCpenney1)).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(wrapper.find(LineJCpenney1)).toHaveLength(1);
        expect(wrapper.find(WordJCpenney1)).toHaveLength(1);
        //await eventually(() => expect(wrapper.find("WordJCpenney1").text()).toEqual("Company"))
    });
    it('should render whole Form body component', () => {        
        wrapper = shallow(<jcpenney1 />);
        var formbodyJcpenney = wrapper.find(FormBodyComponent);       
        expect(formbodyJcpenney.props().parentId).toEqual(propIds.formId);

    });
});
```

So here I am simply checking whether Formbody child component consists of property parentId or not.
And while I run the test I am getting the following error:

```
› 1 snapshot updated.
 FAIL  src/components/tests/jcpenney1.test.js
  ● JC penney1 container testing › should render whole Form body component

    Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

      48 |         wrapper = shallow(<jcpenney1 />);
      49 |         var addressJcpenney = wrapper.find(FormBodyComponent);
    > 50 |         expect(addressJcpenney.props().parentId).toEqual(propIds.formId);
         |                                ^
      51 |         //expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
      52 |         //expect(wrapper.contains('AddressJCpenney1')).to.equal(true);
      53 |     });

      at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1875:17)
      at ShallowWrapper.props (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1140:21)
      at Object.props (src/components/tests/jcpenney1.test.js:50:32)
```

For Details error click this link:

[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KStMM.png)

Please Help me how to fix this problem

Comment: `shallow` doesn't render child components so you'll either need to [dive](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) to your component or use `mount`

Comment: I also have tried with mount but still having same problem.Actually I have multiple component inside Jcpenney component, so how to pass them in mount

Answer (score 0):

the problem is wrapper.find() is not finding the component.

you imported the component but I think you exported it wrong. the way you imported shows that you `export default` the component or maybe you forgot to export it. check it if you `exported` or `default exported`

or

`wrapper.find("withStyles(FormBodyComponent)")` //you do not need to import